# How do you solve for current or voltage in series circuit when you only have resistance total and P1?

Tags: voltage, current, series

Total resistance 900 ohm
P1 is 48mW
Needing I or V to solve the rest of the equation or power total

Comment: Generally, you plug those numbers in a formula. What formulas you know that you can combine to relate resistance and power?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 1):

Well, we all know Ohm's law:

$$\text{V}=\text{I}\cdot\color{red}{\text{R}}\tag1$$

We also know that the power in a resistor is given by:

$$\color{red}{\text{P}}=\text{V}\cdot\text{I}\tag2$$

So, combining:

$$\color{red}{\text{P}}=\text{I}\cdot\color{red}{\text{R}}\cdot\text{I}=\text{I}^2\cdot\color{red}{\text{R}}\tag3$$

> All the red letters are the things we know. So ... !

Answer (score 0):

For a series circuit, let V be the voltage across the circuit and I be the total current. We know the total resistance (say R).
From Ohm's law
$$
V = I \cdot R
$$
Also the total power (P is known) consumed in the circuit is given by:
$$
P = V \cdot I
$$
So if you want to find the voltage across the series circuit, then substitute I from Ohm's law in the power equation
$$
P = V \cdot \Big(\frac{V}{R}\Big) = \frac{V^2}{R}
$$
$$
V = \sqrt{P \cdot R}
$$
And if you want to find current, then substitute V:
$$
P = (I \cdot R) \cdot I = I^2 \cdot R
$$
$$
I = \sqrt{\frac{P}{R}}
$$